# how to validate an email address on php script

Tags: php, html, validation

How do I add a email validation to this pdo script. the user enters their email address in 'textfield'. simply if the email address entered is not in the database I want it to redirect to fail.html

```
<?php

$host=""; // Host name 
$username=""; // Mysql username 
$password=""; // Mysql password 
$db_name=""; // Database name 
$tbl_name="orders"; // Table name  
$email = $_POST['textfield'];


        $db = new PDO('mysql:host='.$host.
                          ';dbname='.$db_name.
                          ';charset=UTF-8',
                    $username, $password);
        $stmt = $db->prepare('SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE `email`=:email LIMIT 1');
        $stmt->bindValue(':email', $email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $stmt->execute();
        $result = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        echo "The is: ".$result['name'].", and mail is: ".$result['email']." . Status: ".$result['status'];


  ?>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a regular expression to validate an email address](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/201323/using-a-regular-expression-to-validate-an-email-address)

Comment: rowCount will tell you if it exists http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php

Comment: add an if-else condition...

Comment: VALID = email that is not on the database

Comment: Sorry, I misread the question and it's not possible to edit a close request.

Comment: I think they want to validate that it's in a database, not that it fits any predefined format.

Comment: correct. simply if the email address entered is not in the database I want it to redirect to fail.html

Answer (score 2):

```
if($stmt->rowCount()>0)
{
    echo "The result is: ".$result['name'].", and mail is: ".$result['email']." . Status: ".$result['status'];
}
else
{
    echo "Email not found in the database!";
}
```

Instead of `echo`ing an error message, you can redirect to another page (only if nothing has already been sent to the browser):

```
header('Location: fail.html');
```

Or you can include the file to display it in the current page:

```
require 'fail.html';
```

Or you can use it in a form input field:

```
echo '<input name="login" type="text" value="' . $result['name'] . '>';
```

The field has its **name** attribute set to **login**, so you will be able to refer to it once the form is submitted.

Comment: thanks works. If i want to display using textfield by '<input type="text" value="<?php echo $result['name']; ?>" /> rather than echo "The result is: ".$result['name']....... how would I go about changing the validation?

Comment: not sure why but when i replace echo "Email not found in the database!"; with header('Location: fail.html'); it does not redirect if email is wrong

Comment: I wrote in my answer **(only if nothing has already been sent to the browser)**. Read [Headers already sent](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8028957/1409082) to learn how to fix the failing header redirect.

Comment: ok got it now. the textfield where I want to display the results is in the body of the page. Can I echo the results in the body rather than in the PHP script.